# Problem compiling Ionic (Angular) app in Android

Tags: android, angular, conceptual, ionic5

I have an app made in Ionic5 framework with the support of Angular, when I run ionic serve --lab, the android app works without problem but the problem is that when I export the project to Android Studio with (ionic capacitor copy android) and I run the app on my device suddenly crashes and stops.

I have been looking for information but I have not found any useful data. My question is more generic than this platform is used to. What error detecting techniques I should use (Android Studio, npm vulnerabilities) and what are some typical cases that generate this error?

I let some posible useful project data:

- I use Firebase for database and back-end services.
- NPM warn me due to the fact that I have 10 vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Ther could be a number of reasons for this.
Try running opening chrome://inspect/#devices where you can select your device and see all console logs.
Also try syncing your gradle files in android studio

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed just some advice about how to get the error that's stopping the app